# Geometric interpretation of integral, D=2

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f$ be a real valued function, and $D$ some domain of $\mathbb R^2$. What is the geometric meaning of the integral

$\int_D dx dy \delta(y-f(x))$

? What is the relation with the length of the curve $y=f(x)$ inside $D$?

Comment: When you say "relation" do you mean 'relationship' or http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28mathematics%29

Comment: This integral has no relation with the curve length except that given by the isoperimetric inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that the domain $D$ is delimited by two curves $y_0(x)$ and $y_1(x)$ for $x\in(x_0,x_1)$.

Integrating first on $y$, the integral reduces to

$$\int_D dx\, dy\, \delta(y-f(x))=\int_{x=x_0}^{x=x_1}\int_{y=y_0(x)}^{y_1(x)} dx\, dy\, \delta(y-f(x))=\int_{x=x_0}^{x=x_1}dx\,f(x).$$

This is the ordinary area under the curve $y=f(x)$.

More precisely, the inner integral is nonzero if $y=f(x)$ occurs in the integration range, so that one must consider only the portions of the domain such that $y_0(x)\le f(x)\le y_1(x)$, i.e. such that the graph of $f$ intersects $D$. You can generalize to more complex domains.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The geometric meaning of the double integral is to find the volume under a surface.

Imagining this visually, $f$ appears to be a function in one variable, or rather it does not depend on $y$. First imagine f(x) on a regular 2D graph, then imagine it in 3D with the extra $y$ axis. $f(x)$ has the same shape at all $y$ values.

the dirac delta function is defined as

$\delta(x) = \infty$ when $x = 0$

and

$\delta(x) = 0$ when $x \neq 0$

Since its zero everywhere else, we only need to be concerned with evaluating the integral for values where the thing inside the dirac delta function is zero.

ie:

Where $y - f(x) = 0$

this happens to be the curve $y = f(x)$

So there is this special set of points where $y = f(x)$  which contribute to the integral.

Comment: Thanks. Would you then agree that $\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}  dx dy \delta(y-x)=L$ ?

Comment: Could you post your working for this as part of the question?

Comment: @Giuseppe: not at all, the length of the curve is computed as $\int\sqrt{f'^2(x)+1}\,dx$.

Comment: $\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}dx \int_{-L/2}^{L/2} dy \delta(y-x)=\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}dx \int_{-L/2-x}^{L/2-x} dz \delta(z)=\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}dx=L$. Works because $x<=L/2, x>=-L/2$. I understand that the relation with curve length is not obvious, though.

Comment: Why the down vote? Have I made a mistake?